# Load More option not working in Laravel AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to fetch blogs using AJAX function in Laravel. But it is not working, neither showing any **error**. What I want is to display a `load more` button from where more blogs will be loaded using AJAX request. Here is my front-end code:

```
     <div class="panel-body">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                  <div id="post_data"></div>
                </div>
```

And my **ajax** script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
load_data('', _token);

function load_data(id="", _token)
{

 $.ajax({
  url:"{{ route('loadmore.load_data') }}",
  method:"POST",
  data:{id:id, _token:_token},
  success:function(data)
  {
   $('#load_more_button').remove();
   $('#post_data').append(data);
  }
 })
}

$(document).on('click', '#load_more_button', function(){
 var id = $(this).data('id');
 $('#load_more_button').html('<b>Loading...</b>');
 load_data(id, _token);
});
});
```

Here is my route:

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/loadmore', 'LoadMoreController@load_data')->name('loadmore.load_data');
```

Here is the **controller** function:

**LoadMoreController.php**

```
class LoadMoreController extends Controller
{
  public function load_more(){
    function load_data(Request $request)
   {
    if($request->ajax())
    {
     if($request->id > 0)
     {
      $data = DB::table('blogs')
         ->where('blog_id', '<', $request->id)
         ->orderBy('blog_id', 'DESC')
         ->limit(6)
         ->get();
     }

     else

     {
      $data = DB::table('blogs')
         ->orderBy('blog_id', 'DESC')
         ->limit(6)
         ->get();
     }

     $output = '';
     $last_id = '';

     if(!$data->isEmpty())
     {
      foreach($data as $row)
      {
       $output .= '
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <h3 class="text-info"><b>'.$row->blog_title.'</b></h3>
         <p>'.$row->blog_content.'</p>
         <br />
         <br />
         <hr />
        </div>
       </div>
       ';
       $last_id = $row->id;
      }
      $output .= '
      <div id="load_more">
       <button type="button" name="load_more_button" class="btn btn-success form-control" data-id="'.$last_id.'" id="load_more_button">Load More</button>
      </div>
      ';
     }
     else
     {
      $output .= '
      <div id="load_more">
       <button type="button" name="load_more_button" class="btn btn-info form-control">No Data Found</button>
      </div>
      ';
     }
     echo $output;
    }
   }
  }
}
```

I'll be happy to provide any other details if needed or asked. Any suggestions/solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: change your loadmore route to GET instead of POST (you're doing a getter request anyway) to fix your issue

Comment: `function load_data(id="", _token)` is this valid JavaScript ? Optional parameters don't make sense before mandatory ones

Comment: @N69S changing method didn't work

Comment: @apokryfos I have tried to implement this, 
https://www.webslesson.info/2019/02/ajax-jquery-load-more-data-in-laravel.html
you can check this link. And have your further comments

Comment: I think The issue in your controller. echo $output; section not execute. Can you check that?

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe yes sure

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe do you need any further details? I'll be happy to provide if any is needed

Comment: Any other method to implement this feature will be also appreciated

Comment: $('#post_data').append("test data here"); What will happen if you add this code segment instead of $('#post_data').append(data); Is it appear in your post_data div?

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe thanks for your precious suggestions. There were multiple issues, and I have resolved all of them. It works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel version 8**

**web.php**
*Here is route file below:*

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
 
    Route::get('/loadmore', [App\Http\Controllers\LoadMoreController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('/loadmore/load_data', [App\Http\Controllers\LoadMoreController::class, 'load_data'])->name('loadmore.load_data');
```